# WebView2 runtime in setup project

Tags: .net, visual-studio, setup-project, webview2

How can I include WebView2 runtime in the setup project?
VisualStudio 2017, C # application.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/distribution

Comment: I solved it in such a way that I also install the small bootstrapper (exe) and run it at the end of the installation process via the installer class (in override void commit (IDictionary savedState)).

I was looking how I could do it via requirement (Setup Project / Properties / Prerequisites ..)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it in such a way that I also install the small bootstrapper (exe) and run it at the end of the installation process via the installer class (in override void commit (IDictionary savedState)).

Comment: How did you do that?

Comment: Would also like to know how to do that? Hopefully possible to have it install silently, or at least without user input.